# Outputing data from a Dictionary<string, int> to a table in Visual Studio c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dictionary

I'm trying to display information stored in a Dictionary so that the integers are left aligned like they would be in a table.

I deliberated writing a method to create two labels in a row of a 'Table layout panel' then calling this method for specific keys but it seemed long winded. Is there a simpler way?

a sample of the data:

```
{[Board,1]}
{[Messages Transmitted, 75877814]}
{[ISR Count, 682900312]}
{[Bus Errors, 0]}
{[Data Errors, 0]}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably also use a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) control.

You can create one, set the View to Details, add two columns and then add the items like:

```
  Dictionary<string, int> itemsSource = new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "Board", 1 }, { "Messages Transmitted", 75877814 }, {"ISR Count", 682900312}, {"Bus Errors", 0}, {"Data Errors", 0}};

    foreach (var item in itemsSource)
    { 
        ListViewItem listItem = new ListViewItem(item.Key);
        listItem.SubItems.Add(item.Value.ToString());

        listView1.Items.Add(listItem);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and look into PadRight. That should do the trick ;)

Comment: Look at this example. Instead of char being '.' just leave blank.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36f2hz3a.aspx